# Php post method not getting data from url

Tags: php, wordpress, post, http-post

I have an URL which is to be used for getting post data after pasting and pressing enter in the browser.
My link is : 
`http://vtrails.us/mixtape-builder/?song_urls=http://vtrails.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mpthreetest.mp3&song_artist=ganja`

```
<?php                       
    if(isset($_POST['song_urls']) && !empty($_POST['song_urls'])){
        $song_url = $_POST['song_urls'];
        $song_artist = $_POST['song_artist'];
    }
    echo $song_url;
    echo $song_artist;
?>
```

But i am not getting any of them.So what can i do now?

Comment: rehmat answer is right, but there is two other issues with your code: 1. you're not testing for `song_artist` existence and 2. the `echo` should be in the `if` condition as if it's not get validated PHP will throw errors (you're possibly trying to `echo` vars that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` you will get desired result:

Here is the code

```
<?php                       
   if(isset($_POST['song_urls']) && !empty($_POST['song_urls'])){
        $song_url = $_POST['song_urls'];
        $song_artist = $_POST['song_artist'];
   }
   echo $song_url;
   echo $song_artist;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its `$_GET`, not `$_POST`. Do this:

```
<?php                       
    if(isset($_GET['song_urls']) && !empty($_GET['song_urls'])){
        $song_url = $_GET['song_urls'];
        $song_artist = $_GET['song_artist'];
    }
    echo $song_url;
    echo $song_artist;
?>
```